# SQL Validation to exists in where clause via certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hi I'm trying to put on a validation on my where clause. But this validation needs only to exist when a certain condition is met else i dont need this validation.

I tried but i am not getting my expected output. Maybe I missed something? Please help

```
 WHERE (CASE
           WHEN 1 = (SELECT DECODE (PARAMETER_VALUE, 'FALSE', 1, 2)
                       FROM TABLE_A
                      WHERE PARAMETER_NAME = 'STUDENT_STATUS')
           THEN
              INVALID_STAT
           ELSE
              ' '
        END) = 'Y'
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson maybe  you can suggest? help :(

Comment: What is the type of INVALID_STAT?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson its a column, text

Comment: What is table_a, don't you need some reference to whatever table you have in the main query (from/join) so you get  the right row or does table_a hold some kind of global parameters?

Comment: TABLE_A is a reference table.

Comment: i need invalid_stat to appear only when the condition on the reference table is met

Comment: I don't think I can help you any more, have you tried to break it down in smaller pieces? Check that the `SELECT DECODE...` works, check that the `CASE WHEN...` works, check that `INVALID_STAT` actually contains 'Y' where you expect it to.

Comment: would it not be better performance to move this from the where clause into a flag column. Then filter down on the flag.

Comment: Your code is [working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=549a503d8b7fcaf17353063a3533edf7), but if You want to ignore `invalid_stat` when student status is not 'FALSE' then change `else ' '` to `else 'Y'`. You can also rewrite this [simpler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=db4feda92f91110e03ed03718c429251), but I don't know if this is what you want. You only said that you don't get expected output, please explain.

Comment: To be honest your question is not clear enough, can you include the expected output and also the output you are getting by that query? and please also briefly explain what do you mean by 'when a certain condition is met'

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing the last `' '` to `'Y'`. So when the query returns a result it converts to

```
WHERE INVALID_STAT = 'Y'
```

And when the query doesn't return any result it converts to -

```
WHERE 'Y' = 'Y'
```

Thus ignoring the condition.